# Android M Google API's to use Google Maps and other permissions

Tags: android, android-maps, android-6.0-marshmallow

I have Android M set up for my project and could build fine. However, When i launch the app, i see the following error and app doesn't launch:

```
<06-23 11:53:24.833 32416 32416 W System.err: java.lang.RuntimeException: **Unable to create application xxxxx: java.lang.SecurityException: "gps" location provider requires ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION permission.**
06-23 11:53:24.833 32416 32416 W System.err:    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4697)
06-23 11:53:24.833 32416 32416 W System.err:    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap1(ActivityThread.java)
06-23 11:53:24.833 32416 32416 W System.err:    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1404)
06-23 11:53:24.833 32416 32416 W System.err:    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
06-23 11:53:24.833 32416 32416 W System.err:    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
06-23 11:53:24.833 32416 32416 W System.err:    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5401)
06-23 11:53:24.833 32416 32416 W System.err:    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
06-23 11:53:24.833 32416 32416 W System.err:    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:725)
06-23 11:53:24.833 32416 32416 W System.err:    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:615)
06-23 11:53:24.833 32416 32416 W System.err: Caused by: **java.lang.SecurityException: "gps" location provider requires ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION permission**.
06-23 11:53:24.833 32416 32416 W System.err:    at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1599)
06-23 11:53:24.833 32416 32416 W System.err:    at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1552)
06-23 11:53:24.833 32416 32416 W System.err:    at android.location.ILocationManager$Stub$Proxy.requestLocationUpdates(ILocationManager.java:598)
06-23 11:53:24.834 32416 32416 W System.err:    at android.location.LocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.java:880)
06-23 11:53:24.834 32416 32416 W System.err:    at android.location.LocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.java:464)
```

I have provided all these permissions access_fine_location, network_state, internet and access_coarse_location in my manifest file as "PROTECTED_NORMAL" So that they are available at install time.

I also noticed that Google API's were missing from Android M preview and may be thats causing the issue?? not sure though. Wondering if anyone came across the same issue and a possible solution?

part of manifest file:

```
 <uses-sdk
   android:minSdkVersion ="MNC"
    android:targetSdkVersion ="MNC" />

 <permission
    android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"
    android:protectionLevel="normal" />

 <permission
    android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"
    android:protectionLevel="normal" />

 <permission
    android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"
    android:protectionLevel="normal" />

 <permission
    android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"
    android:protectionLevel="normal" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

<application>
 <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />
 **activity declarations**
</application>
```

Thanks!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I have provided all these permissions access_fine_location, network_state, internet and access_coarse_location in my manifest file as "PROTECTED_NORMAL" So that they are available at install time.

No. Those permissions are defined by the platform, not you. You cannot redefine them to have lower protection levels, and the `LOCATION` permissions are `dangerous`. And, as [the M Developer Preview documentation](http://developer.android.com/preview/features/runtime-permissions.html#coding) states, those are permissions that you need to request at runtime.

> a possible solution?

Request the location permissions from the user before attempting to use the map. Note that I have not tried maps on the M Developer Preview yet, so it may be that this is not supported at all right now.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response @CommonsWare.. I am trying to access maps (to get location etc...) in my application class and hence needed to give location/maps permission at the time of installation. So did some tinkering with the permission levels which i now understand is not right.  Google doc says "use PROTECTION_SIGNATURE or have the app as part of the system image" to grant permissions at install time. I tried signature and it wasn't working. I cannot have it as a system image.

Comment: @praveen_85: AFAIK, there is no way to get location permissions at install time on M.