# Cannot get my location using the emulataor

Tags: android, google-maps

I am trying to develop a Google Map application.

The demo application works fine on a real device but fails on the emulator.

the logcat output is as follows:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{il.co.talkie.mapdemo/il.co.talkie.mapdemo.MapDemoActivity}: java.lang.SecurityException: "passive" location provider requires ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION permission.
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2416)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
 Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: "passive" location provider requires ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION permission.
        at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1599)
        at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1552)
        at android.location.ILocationManager$Stub$Proxy.requestLocationUpdates(ILocationManager.java:606)
        at android.location.LocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.java:880)
        at android.location.LocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.java:464)
        at il.co.talkie.mapdemo.MapDemoActivity.getMyLocation(MapDemoActivity.java:170)
        at il.co.talkie.mapdemo.MapDemoActivity.onCreate(MapDemoActivity.java:106)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Line 170 of MapDemoActivity is

```
locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0,0, this);
```

The manifest file has these permissions (otherwise it will not work on a real device) as can be seen here:

**Manifest.XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="il.co.talkie.mapdemo" >

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

<permission
    android:name="com.javapapers.currentlocationinmap.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="@string/google_maps_key" />

    <activity
        android:name=".MapDemoActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_map_demo" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

I would like to use the emulator to get my location - it displays the google map and it finds locations of addresses I provide, but it refuses to get my location - so I can not calculate distances properly.

What is wrong?
The emulator I use  was created for API 23 and target Google API.
Any help will be welcomed.

Comment: OK, from the answer of @headuck I understood that I need to ask for permission in my app, so that it will be compatible with API 23. However when I try to check for permission I get errors:            ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this, android.permission.READ_SMS); 
gives an error cannot resolve  "permission", and 
            ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this, Manifest.permission.READ_SMS);
gives an error cannot resolve "READ_SMS"

Comment: Figured it out: although the examples pointed below do not have it  bewteen quotes I saw it somewhere else' so the right call is 

ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this, "Manifest.permission.READ_SMS");

Answer (score 0):

If you are using emulator on Android M , you will need to request permission from user despite your manifest. See

[ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION permission error emulator only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32224534/access-fine-location-permission-error-emulator-only)

[Android M Google API's to use Google Maps and other permissions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31038978/android-m-google-apis-to-use-google-maps-and-other-permissions)

You may check out articles / tutorials e.g. [this](http://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/things-you-need-to-know-about-android-m-permission-developer-edition/en) to work with the new system or just target a lower API <= 22

Answer (score 0):

Error is occuring because of this problem:

Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: "passive" location provider requires ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION permission.

Just add a new permission to your app manifest:

uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>

Comment: As noted in the question above the permission is already in the manifest, otherwise it would not work in a real device (likely to be < Android 6).

Comment: try to use Genymotion Simulator from here https://www.genymotion.com/ , you will not get this problem. in android simultor sometimes location control do not work properly.